# Laravel - Faking route in PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, phpunit

I've been writing some tests in PHPUnit (version 7.4.3), but in some files in my project (a Laravel 5.7.12 JSON API) I need to use the route (`/users/123/posts/456`), but when PHPUnit calls the route, `request()->getPathInfo()` returns `""`.

Is there some way to fake this, or fill it with the correct data?

I am calling the route using `$this->getJson(route('users.index'));` in the test class.

Answer (score 1):

You should Mock the getJson method in order to return a fixture of your response.

As you are unit testing your app, you have to mock any external depedency or class to be sure you are only testing your current function.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! It makes sense indeed to mock the request, so I gave it a try, however it doesn't work yet. Can you maybe take a look at the snippet below and tell me if I do something horribly wrong?

```$request = Mockery::mock(Request::class, [
            'pathInfo'   => '/v1/users/self',
        ]);

        $this->app->instance(Request::class, $request);

        dd(request());```

I got the idea from the following source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/testing/mocking-the-request-url?page=1